# Java Socket Server not reading Line

Tags: java

I have following Server:

```
public final class Server implements Runnable {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;

    Server() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean running = true;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000);
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            while (running) {
                String data = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(data);
                if (data.equals("quit")) {
                    running = false;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

and following Client:

```
public class Client {
    private Socket socket;
    private PrintWriter out;

    public Client() {
        socket = null;

        try {
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000);
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (final UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Address unknown "
                               + e.getMessage());
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error connecting to the Server "
                               + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(String msg) {
        out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

I am able to establish an initial connection, but as soon as I execute the `sendMessage()` Method, the server doesn't print out anything. Do you know why I cannot receive a message?

Comment: Show the code that calls `sendMessage()`. Also, you don't need to set `socket = null` in the beginning of the constructor, what do you think it would contain?

Comment: @Kayaman I am using BlueJ so I call the sendMessage method on the Client object. I can just right click the object and then execute the method like this.

Comment: Well, then you're on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server reads with `in.readLine()` while the client prints with `print()` (no new line). So the server is waiting for new line to appear which never happens.

Try writing with `println()` in the client.

Also, you need to flush your writer: add `out.flush()`. This is required to make the writer to actually send its payload.

Comment: I've added a note about flushing the reader. This makes the program work on my machine.

Comment: The flush did it. I love you! Been sitting on that one like 5 hours for some dumb shit. But thank you a lot!!!!